# Currency success event in Adobe analytics

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

I have created a currency success event in adobe analytics and passing amount selected by user in this event. The code I am using to send this event is as below:

s.events="event2";
s.products=";Amount;;;event2=25000";

I am referring this article http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1966020&seqNum=4 . Am I using the correct code ? Because if I check the data in adobe analytics, I am not able to see any data collected for this event.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: All by itself that syntax is correct. Re-check to make sure things are configured properly. Did you configure `event2` as a currency event in the interface? Do you see the data being sent to omniture from your page? To the correct report suite? What report(s) are you trying to look at?

Comment: s.t() or s.tl() call is something else to think about. If that's in an onclick handler using s.tl(), you'd have to make some adjustments.

Comment: @CrayonViolent Yes, I have configured the **event2** as a currency event in the interface. Also I have checked in the omnibug and see the data being sent to omniture. I am looking at the same report suite where the data is sent.

Comment: @BrettAHale I have added the call and also see the data firing in the omnibug

Comment: What report(s) are you trying to look at?

Comment: I am looking at the product "Amount" with the metric as "event2".